# C string processing

Tags: c, arrays, string

I know that when passing strings between functions

char *str is almost the same as char str[n] in function header.

However i do wanna know why this would work and whats the difference between these 2 when working with string

I found that if i declare a "char *in" first then assign a string to it "in=string;" 
this wont work

can some one tell me whats behind this?

Is there anyway I can assign a array to another array? like in Java

Thanks

```
char[] one;
char[] two={'a','b'};
one=two;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char[] one;
```

The syntax is wrong. This isn't Java.

```
char* one;
char two[]={'a','b'};
one = two;
```

This works because array decays to a pointer.

> "char *str is almost the same as char str[n] in function header."

**NO**. Arrays and pointers are two different concepts. They both aren't the same.

Comment: As a function parameter declaration, `char *str` and `char[n]` *are* identical; they both declare `str` as a pointer.  (This applies *only* to parameters.)

Answer (score 0):

`Array` and `Pointer` are two different concepts. I guess you should start slowly with basics, this is one paper that explains : http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/string/array-vs-ptr/

Comment: the concepts of string and arrays are the same in cpp and c? thanks for the link anyway

Comment: In C++, you have `std::string`, which is a class for handling string. However, you can still use C-style string. In C, `string` is a concept not a type, an array of character ending with `\0` (NULL) character. That's the difference!

Comment: @xjaphx: `NULL` is a null *pointer* constant, not a null character.

Comment: @Keith Thompson: ok, NUL then :|

Answer (score 0):

The best explanation I've seen for the relationship between arrays and pointers in C (and C++) is section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com).